# Having an issue renaming Excel worksheet

Tags: c#, excel

I have write a console C# program to generate a Spreadsheet. However when I try to name the second sheet, that name over writes the first sheet.

```
///// create sheet1
Workbook wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet);
Worksheet WorkSheet = (Worksheet)wb.Worksheets[1];
WorkSheet.Name = "Work Sheet";

///// create sheet2

wb.Sheets.Add();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet staffCosts = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)wb.Worksheets[2];
staffCosts.Name = "Staff Costs";
```

Something I have missed and no doubt it will be simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default the new worksheet becomes the first sheet. All other sheets are shifted to the right, so `Worksheets[2]` refers to what used to be `Worksheets[1]`.

In any case this is how you should have written it:

```
staffCosts = wb.Sheets.Add();
staffCosts.Name = "Staff Costs";
```

Comment: Perfect thanks for that... Plus the explanation really makes sense too. I think I understand it allot better now thanks.